# Get previous element text after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

In the following structure

```
<div class="class name with spaces_9">
 <div class="class name with spaces_8">
  <div class="class name with spaces_7">
    <div class="class name with spaces_6">
     <span class="class name with spaces_5"> price number </span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="class name with spaces_3"> some stuff</div>
<div class="class name with spaces_3">
 <form id="123">
  <div class="class name with spaces_2">
   <div class="class name with spaces_1">
    <a id="content" class="button_class">Button text</a>
   </div>  
  </div> 
 </form>
</div>
```

My purpose is to put string from the span with the class name "class name with spaces_5" into some variable but after user clicks the button in an "a" tag. Such a strange purpose comes from the fact that in actual span on my site i got the price number. There are several blocks with such buttons and prices and all elements have simular class names but different prices. I need to put this code in GTM custom java script variable or custom html tag. Anyway, i need to get value from an apper span inside some amount of divs after button was clicked.

Comment: Could you include your current script in the post please so we can have a look at it to see why it is not working? If possible, add a code snippet to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some sort of data-widget, in that way you could have several elements in your page with a js widget that iterated them.

Something like:

Html:

```
<div data-widget="foobar">
  <div class="class name with spaces_6">
   <span class="class name with spaces_5"> price number </span>
  </div> 
  <div class="class name with spaces_1">
    <a id="content" class="button_id">Button text</a>
  </div>  
</div>
```

js:

```
$('[data-widget="foobar"]').each(function() {
  var $elm = $(this);
  var $price = $('.class name with spaces_5', $elm);
  var $trigger = $('.button_id', $elm);

  $($trigger).on('click', function() {
    console.log($price); // Or do whatever you wan't with the value
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get the previous value by using

```
 $(this).prevAll("input[type=text]").val()
```

Live Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/z7hw8/